# Событие на изменение члена класса

Tags: c#, .net

Событие на отслеживание изменения переменной выглядит так:

```
public bool Flag
{
    get { return _flag; }
    set
    {
        _flag = value;
        if (Flag == true)
        {
            // Собственно событие
        }
    }
}
bool _flag;
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы событие выполнялось при изменении члена класса, который прописан в Program.cs?

```
class WarningFlag
    {
        public static bool Alarm = false;
    }
```

Иными словами, есть класс WarningFlag, есть член класса Alarm. Как будет выглядеть событие, которое будет отслеживать изменение WarningFlag.Alarm?

Comment: что вам мешает сделать то же самое?

Comment: Возможно, не до конца описал проблему. Форм несколько, а член класса WarningFlag.Alarm выполняет роль глобальной переменной (знаю, что нельзя его так называть, но тем не менее). То есть при изменении свойства этого члена класса должно выполняться то или иное событие на нескольких формах.
Насколько я понял, реализовать описанное выше (событие на отслеживание переменной) в данном случае не выйдет. Если я неправ, то прошу поправить/сказать, как правильно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614190/inotifypropertychanged-and-static-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в вашем классе событие и вызывайте его при изменении свойства Flag.  Примерно так:

```
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public event MyDelegate OnFlagChanged;

    public bool Flag
    {
        get { return _flag; }
        set
        {
            _flag = value;
            if (_flag)
            {
                OnFlagChanged?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _flag;
```

Затем в нужных местах (ult-то в тех формах, о которых dds пишете в комментарии) навешайте на него обработчики:

```
_instance.OnFlagChanged += EventHandler;
```

где `_instance` - экземпляр вашего класса, содержащего свойство `Flag`, а `EventHandler` - некий метод, обрабатывающий само событие

Comment: `if (_flag)` разве это показывает, что поле изменилось?

Comment: @tym32167 это проверяет, что `_flag` равен true, собственно, то же самое, что интересует автора вопроса судя по приведённому им коду

Comment: @DreamChild, `INotifyPropertyChanged`? :)

Comment: Я думаю, автор не понимает сам, что его код не покажет что поле изменилось

Comment: @DreamChild Спасибо, стало понятнее. Тем не менее, не ясно другое. С одной стороны, понятно, что событие помещается непосредственно в класс (в моём случае - в класс WarningFlag"). Но как выглядит событие на другой форме, которое, собственно, будет автоматически отслеживать изменение переменной?

Comment: Всё, разобрался! Затупил в самом простом месте.